# Building filters for WMS service

Tags: wms

Is there a way of retrieving the attributes of a WMS layer that can be used to construct a filter?

Unless I'm mistaken GetCapabilities does not do this and GetFeatureInfo requires a feature to be selected via x/y or i/j

Other thought was to use GeoNetwork for playing back attribute metadata but this then requires a maintenance step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DescribeFeature` request to find out about one or more layers as described in the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#describelayer).

Try http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS%20&version=1.1.1%20&request=DescribeLayer%20&layers=sf:roads,topp:tasmania_roads,nurc:mosaic%20&outputFormat=application/json

To get a response like:

```
{"version":"1.1.1","layerDescriptions"  
[{"layerName":"sf:roads", "owsURL":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?", "owsType":"WFS","typeName":"sf:roads"},
{"layerName":"topp:tasmania_roads", "owsURL":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?", "owsType":"WFS","typeName":"topp:tasmania_roads"},
{"layerName":"nurc:mosaic", "owsURL":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?", "owsType":"WCS","typeName":"nurc:mosaic"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetFeatureInfo request may give you the names of attributes, depending on the info_format requested, but it should be noted that a service provider may choose which attributes to return and can alias the attribute names.  Probably the best format choice is `application/vnd.ogc.gml`.